# Rational points of an open subset of a group scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, valuation-theory, group-schemes

Let $K$ be an algebraically closed valued field with valuation ring $\mathcal{O}$ (assume the valuation is non-trivial). Let $G$ be a group scheme over $\mathcal{O}$, $g\in G(\mathcal{O})$ and $V\subseteq G$ an open subscheme. Does there exists an open subscheme $U\subseteq G$ such that $$g\cdot V(\mathcal{O})=U(\mathcal{O})?$$

Comment: Let me try to answer my own question. This is probably true in general. We may define a left-transition map of scheme $l_g: G\to G$. It is an isomorphism, hence an open immersion. We define $U=l_g(V)$.

Comment: So, to be explicit: as an open subscheme of $G$, and thus as locally ringed space, $U$ has underlying topological  space $|U|= l_g(| V|)$, and structure sheaf the restriction of  that of $G$.